# Detect Injected Content in Website

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if anyone knew how to detect injected content on your website using JavaScript e.g. from adware or ISPs?

So if a user had adware installed on their computer you would be able to detect this and notify the user.

EDIT: I think this would be the best solution: http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/security/web-tripwire.html

Comment: Why not just walk the DOM post-render, checking against a reference rendering?

Comment: probably best to walk the DOM and do some kind of check sum.

Comment: Thanks. What do you guys think of this solution: https://paul.kinlan.me/detecting-injected-content/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Consider CSP - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP.

You can enable reporting to a server by using adding the `report-uri` directive to the `Content-Security-Policy` header, e.g. :

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; report-uri http://reportcollector.example.com/collector.cgi
```